# Saving Redshift Matadata

Tags: metadata, ddl, amazon-redshift

we are using Redshift as our EDW and we have quite a bit of tables and view there. at the moment we keeping all DDL's in our organisation's knowledge centre, but this is basically copy and paste and not very smart. is there any other option that is quicker better to do so?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you meant be "copy and paste" but you can try to put all the scripts in a github/ SVN repository and make sure that all the DDLs actually get fired using the scripts from the repo.

We did this using git and Jenkins (and little bit of Shell programs to do the code checkins and checkouts). We blocked all the users from running DDL statements and the Jenkins job would just pull the latest scripts from the repo and deploy it automatically from the RC (release candidate) branch of the repo.

If you need to export the DDL scripts out from the system you can use the script provided by the AWS folks,
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

If you want to automate the checkin process to some code repository, you can build a wrapper python code using this code.

Comment: copy and paste meaning that we are copying the DDL's to a confluence page on every change and that is not comfortable. I do want to keep running the scripts from my redshift client (sqlworkbench/j) but as looking for a convenient  way to export it when I change something